# Vertica currency handeling issue !! how to solve

Tags: database, currency, collation, vertica

Ok i am going thru documentation i got to a point where the collation is the subject

Imagine this :
  in USA you have 30[color=#FF0000].[/color]00$
  in BRAZIL you have 30[color=#FF0000],[/color]00 R$

-how can i solve this !! so that the database won't interpret it wrong ?

Vertica documentation 
[quote]Notes
• Even though ICU locales can normally specify collation, currency, and calendar preferences, Vertica supports only the collation component. The SET DATESTYLE TO ... command provides some aspects of the calendar; [color=#FF0000]only dollars are supported for currency[/color]. Any keywords not relating to collation are rejected.
[/quote]

Comment: Solution to this problem is :LC_ALL=pt_BR.UTF-8
Start Vertica.
On vsql:
dbadmin=> SELECT TO_CHAR(12343148.567890123, 'L999G999G999G999D999999');
          TO_CHAR          
---------------------------
 R$      12.343.148,567890

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I've implemented currency storage is to store the amount in a field and the currency type in another field.

If you're looking to just change the Currency Symbol in the results, check out `Template patterns for Numeric Formatting` page 271 in 6.0 `SQL Reference Manual.pdf`.

That is the only location in the doc that I found 'currency'.

Comment: I don't think i understand !! can you post an example on numeric formatting regarding my issue ?!<br/>

Comment: @UP_TWO My Answer has the wrong page number, it's 270. There are examples in the doc on how to use the formatting.

Comment: Ok i get it but still , even if i change the local to my local(pt_BR)i still get the DOT "." and not comma"," as it should be in pt_BR.<br>See in US currency is 12.23 cents in BR should be 12,23!!!!!!!

Comment: @UP_TWO Can you provide the template pattern you used?

Comment: select to_number('12.23','L999D99');

Comment: select to_number('12,23','L999D99');
- i am having comma as input

Comment: @UP_TWO: Since you are using the `D` in the template and still getting template, I'd suggest hitting up the Vertica forums and seeing what you get from there. Sorry I can't be more exact, haven't had to do locales

Comment: LC_ALL=pt_BR.UTF-8
Start Vertica.
On vsql:
dbadmin=> SELECT TO_CHAR(12343148.567890123, 'L999G999G999G999D999999');
          TO_CHAR          
---------------------------
 R$      12.343.148,567890